# Is there a GUI tool to manage and view Git configuration?

Tags: git, version-control, git-config

Something that shows your current config and allows you to change some.

Comment: You should provide your operating system to get more relevant answers.

Comment: @musiKk I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. :-(

It's no substitute, but `git config -l` can show you all your current settings that you've explicitly set (read: no defaults are shown).  And the [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables) show most of the variables available.